# Watch for the cars

Tags: difference, idioms, phrasal-verbs

> "Watch for the cars! "

When crossing a street with a kid, you would usually say **"watch out!"**. But instead of this, would the phrase above also work ok and mean the same?

Comment: [*watch out*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/watch+out) vs. [*watch for*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/watch+for). They are different. If you are asking a kid to be careful crossing the street, then say "Watch out for cars!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Watch for the cars!

usually means *look for* or *take notice* of the cars since they may be interesting to see sin a parade or car rally.

> Watch out for the cars!

usually means *be careful of the cars*.

Depending on context, both phrases may or may not mean the same thing.

When used with a stern voice and authoritative demeanour these phrases might get used to instruct children to be careful around traffic.

In informal use as a warning, the "out" can get dropped since: 1) it would probably be understood; and 2) one might be in a hurry to get the point across

> Watch *(out)* for *(the)* cars!

When a car is approaching, people, including children, may scream out the shortened form

> CAR(S)!

Similar phrases that get used to instruct children are

> Look out for cars!
>   Look both ways before crossing the road!

Comment: Thank you. But if you google "watch for", there are images of caution signs with the phrase, watch for cars'. What is this about?

Comment: And also then, if a kid is puttig his finger between a door and its frame, which could seriouly hurt his finger, should it be "watch for your finger" or "watch out for your finger"?

Comment: Signage will usually have the minimum number of words to get a safety point across, similar to headlines, since it would be faster to read and space is limited to the size of the sign.

Comment: Usually one would say "Watch out for the door!", "Be careful of the door!", "Don't get your fingers caught in the door!", etc.

Comment: Thank you. I've asked but this question hasn't been answered, and want to add another option as well...
 if a kid is puttig his finger between a door and its frame, which could seriously hurt his finger, should it be "watch for your finger" or "watch out for your finger" or "watch your finger"?

Comment: For fingers, one might say "watch your fingers *(in the door)*" similar to "watch your step" when getting on/off *something*

Comment: Thank you Peter. Then if it is the stairs(steps) to watch for, then you would say, "watch for the steps", or "watch out for the steps"?

Comment: "Watch out for the steps", "be careful of the steps", and the general "watch your step" which can be used for any situation: steps, wet flooring, a gap in the walkway.

Comment: Thank you. So "watch your step" refers to either the stairs(steps) or stepping feet, is it?

Comment: "Watch your step" = "be careful where you are stepping", depending on the situation it could be stairs, gaps, cliffs.

Comment: Thank you. If it refers to the physical outer objects, then would the use of "the" sound correct too, "watch the step(s), not to mention the plural form for them?

Comment: Does anyone else have an opinion on my last comment?